# Driver converts uint64 parameter into int32 negative value

Tags: sql, go, firebird

My Firebird procedure take few parameters with bigint value.
When I call this procedure from go program parameters with type uint64 and value large than max int32/2 stored as negative one.
How can I pass bigint/uint64 value as parameter?

```
import (
   ...
    "database/sql"
    "github.com/arteev/firebirdsql"
)
...
type Data struct {
  Value uint64
  Sum   uint64
  Ts    time.Time
}
...
tx, _ := db.Begin()
st, err := tx.Prepare("execute procedure add_summary(?, ? ,? ,?, ?)")
if err != nil {
    tx.Rollback()
}
defer st.Close()
if _, err := st.Exec(ip, ifKey, port, data.Sum, data.Ts); err != nil {
  ...   
} else {
  ...
}
...
```

Schema/table DDL fragment:

```
CREATE TABLE ADM_SUMMARY (
    ITEM_ID  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PERIOD   CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    VAL      BIGINT NOT NULL,
    DT       TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    UNITS    CHAR(1) NOT NULL
);
```

Procedure DDL fragment:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE ADD_SUMMARY (
    ip varchar(20),
    if_key varchar(20),
    if_num integer,
    val bigint,
    dt timestamp)
as...
```

I wrote little test:
Test code

```
tx, err := db.Begin()
if err != nil {
    tx.Rollback()
}
_, err = tx.Exec("insert into test(B1) values(?)", uint64(2147483648))
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
tx.Commit()
```

DDL of test table:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (
    B1  BIGINT
);
```

Result: B1 = -2147483648

Comment: Are you doing actual big integers or uint64? These are completely different. You may want to show your schema, data types, as well as the actual vs expected outputs.

Comment: My procedure working well in ruby and python scripts. Log in my go program show  that source value of params are type uint64

Comment: You haven't answered any of my questions. Without details, we can't help.

Comment: This is fragment of DDL: CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE ADD_SUMMARY (
    ip varchar(20),
    if_key varchar(20),
    if_num integer,
    val bigint,
    dt timestamp)

Comment: At first glance, the behaviour described sounds like a bug, have you considered reporting it on https://github.com/arteev/firebirdsql (or better yet on https://github.com/nakagami/firebirdsql as that arteev driver seems to be a fork) instead of asking here? Also, BIGINT is a signed 64 bit integer, not unsigned.

Comment: I don't know is the bug of database/sql or arteev/firebirdsql

Comment: Given you say the stored procedure works fine from Python, you already know the problem is not in the database, so the problem is either in your go code, but you don't provide a [mre] so we can't check, or the problem is in the driver.

Comment: I wrote little test: insert into test(B1) values(?). Param - max value for uint64. Created table: CREATE TABLE TEST (
    B1  BIGINT
);  As result in test table value of B1 field: -1

Comment: That is not surprising, because  a BIGINT is a **signed** 64 bit integer. Putting in the uint64 max value will therefor yield -1 (two's complement). Try putting in a smaller value that takes more than 32 bits and less than 64 bits.

Comment: So I would recommend changing to a signed 64 bit int (I don't know if golang has that), or double check that your values are less than or equal to 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF (max value of a signed 64 bit int).

Comment: I sparsely have values large than max uint32 and surely less than 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF. In my test code I used value max int32/2 +1, i.e 0x10000000

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried using https://github.com/nakagami/firebirdsql instead, maybe it is a bug that has been fixed upstream.

Comment: Mark, thank you for your advises! I opened issues on both repositories. I first time used this library github.com/nakagami/firebirdsql. Now I changed library, ran test with parameter max uint64 >> 1 and get result positive but only half of int32 maximum  2147483647

Comment: I got same negative result with value 2147483648  ->  -2147483648

Answer (score 2):

> nakagami added a commit that referenced this issue 2 hours ago fix
> issue #112 92e5c50 nakagami closed this 2 hours ago

After few hours from my bug report it was closed by author.
Bug report at github.com/arteev/firebirdsql still opened.
Thanks to all for participation and  advises.

Comment: Given github.com/arteev/firebirdsql is a fork of github.com/nakagami/firebirdsql , I assume it will get fixed there as well as soon as they sync their fork.